# TypeErrors with integer scalar

Tags: python, numpy

I am getting the following error when I try to run the code and don't know how to fix it (see picture). The error is raised when setting y equal to [train_index]. My train_index is of type int64, and my y varible is a list with integers in it. As can be seen in the code, the y list is changed using a map function.

Pictures are shown here:
[types of the variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YumrJ.png)
[TypeError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OXbj.png)

```
# Load xls sheet with data
doc = xlrd.open_workbook('bank-one_duration.xlsx').sheet_by_index(0)

# Extract attribute names (1st row, column 4 to 12)
attributeNames = doc.row_values(0, 0, 46)

# Extract class names to python list,
# then encode with integers (dict)
classLabels = doc.col_values(44, 1, 4521)
y = list(map(int,classLabels))

# Preallocate memory, then extract excel data to matrix X
X = np.empty((4520, 45))
for i, col_id in enumerate(range(0, 45)):
    X[:, i] = np.asarray(doc.col_values(col_id, 1, 4521))

## Crossvalidation
# Create crossvalidation partition for evaluation
K = 5
CV = model_selection.KFold(n_splits=K,shuffle=True)

M = len(attributeNames)

# Initialize variables
Features = np.zeros((M,K))
Error_train = np.empty((K,1))
Error_test = np.empty((K,1))
Error_train_fs = np.empty((K,1))
Error_test_fs = np.empty((K,1))
Error_train_nofeatures = np.empty((K,1))
Error_test_nofeatures = np.empty((K,1))

k=0
for train_index, test_index in CV.split(X):

    # extract training and test set for current CV fold
    X_train = X[train_index,:]
    y_train = y[train_index]
    X_test = X[test_index,:]
    y_test = y[test_index]
    internal_cross_validation = 10

    # Compute squared error without using the input data at all
    Error_train_nofeatures[k] = np.square(y_train-y_train.mean()).sum()/y_train.shape[0]
    Error_test_nofeatures[k] = np.square(y_test-y_test.mean()).sum()/y_test.shape[0]

    # Compute squared error with all features selected (no feature selection)
    m = lm.LinearRegression(fit_intercept=True).fit(X_train, y_train)
    Error_train[k] = np.square(y_train-m.predict(X_train)).sum()/y_train.shape[0]
    Error_test[k] = np.square(y_test-m.predict(X_test)).sum()/y_test.shape[0]

    # Compute squared error with feature subset selection
    #textout = 'verbose';
    textout = '';
    selected_features, features_record, loss_record = feature_selector_lr(X_train, y_train, internal_cross_validation,display=textout)

    Features[selected_features,k]=1
    # .. alternatively you could use module sklearn.feature_selection
    if len(selected_features) is 0:
        print('No features were selected, i.e. the data (X) in the fold cannot describe the outcomes (y).' )
    else:
        m = lm.LinearRegression(fit_intercept=True).fit(X_train[:,selected_features], y_train)
        Error_train_fs[k] = np.square(y_train-m.predict(X_train[:,selected_features])).sum()/y_train.shape[0]
        Error_test_fs[k] = np.square(y_test-m.predict(X_test[:,selected_features])).sum()/y_test.shape[0]

        figure(k)
        subplot(1,2,1)
        plot(range(1,len(loss_record)), loss_record[1:])
        xlabel('Iteration')
        ylabel('Squared error (crossvalidation)')    

        subplot(1,3,3)
        bmplot(attributeNames, range(1,features_record.shape[1]), -features_record[:,1:])
        clim(-1.5,0)
        xlabel('Iteration')

    print('Cross validation fold {0}/{1}'.format(k+1,K))
    print('Train indices: {0}'.format(train_index))
    print('Test indices: {0}'.format(test_index))
    print('Features no: {0}\n'.format(selected_features.size))

    k+=1

# Inspect selected feature coefficients effect on the entire dataset and
# plot the fitted model residual error as function of each attribute to
# inspect for systematic structure in the residual

f=2 # cross-validation fold to inspect
ff=Features[:,f-1].nonzero()[0]
if len(ff) is 0:
    print('\nNo features were selected, i.e. the data (X) in the fold cannot describe the outcomes (y).' )
else:
    m = lm.LinearRegression(fit_intercept=True).fit(X[:,ff], y)

    y_est= m.predict(X[:,ff])
    residual=y-y_est

    figure(k+1, figsize=(12,6))
    title('Residual error vs. Attributes for features selected in cross-validation fold {0}'.format(f))
    for i in range(0,len(ff)):
       subplot(2,np.ceil(len(ff)/2.0),i+1)
       plot(X[:,ff[i]],residual,'.')
       xlabel(attributeNames[ff[i]])
       ylabel('residual error')


show()
```

Comment: hi @amanden! Please provide full stacktace as the code block just because it's easier to read. Users here are way more ready to help if you provide [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with some input and the desired output.

Comment: Sure! I will make a new post then.